# I need to edit a airflow.cfg file in Azure

Tags: azure, kubernetes, vim, airflow

I install Airflow on Azure Kubernetes service AKS and I'm trying to edit airflow.cfg file on Azure cloud. How can I edit this file?

[image]

Comment: Do you have vim installed? Try the `which vim` command to figure out if you have the vim editor installed at first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If vim is not found, install vim.

Anyway, you don't have to modify airflow.cfg, you can export environmental variables as pointed out in https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/howto/set-config.html#setting-configuration-options

Here you can find all configuration variables available with their environmental variable equivalent https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/configurations-ref.html